# The bevel tool is beveling too steeply

Tags: bevel

[image]

As the picture shows, the bevel is doing it very steeply. What should I do?

Comment: Is the scale of the object uniform?

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply scale to the object before beveling to get a nice result. Go to object mode, select the object you want to bevel, then go to **Object > Apply > Scale**.

In edit mode, select the *edge* not face or vertex that you want to bevel, then press <kbd>B</kbd>.